# Using nested loop on jlabel

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

I'm trying to find the cartesian product and print the result in jlabel but it only shows the last element of my array.

```
int list1 [] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int list2[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; 
        int n1=list1.length; 
int n2=list2.length;
findCart(list1, list2, n1, n2);






void findCart(int arr1[],int arr2[],  
                                    int n, int n1) 
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
          for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) 
            jLabel1.setText("{"+ arr1[i]+", "
                             + arr2[j]+"}, "); 
    }
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped solve your question. If it did, you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concatenate the values before setting the text:

```
void findCart(int arr1[],int arr2[], int n, int n1) 
{       
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) 
        sb.append("{" + arr1[i] + ", " + arr2[j]+"}, "); 
    }
    jLabel1.setText(sb.toString());
}
```